# Merging two protected branches in gitlab after squashing commits

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, branch, merge-conflict-resolution

So the situation is this: we have two protected branches in gitlab "develop", and "test" (over which we dont have permissions to push onto without merge requests), we merged the develop branch to test, deciding to squash the commits as we had to use 100+ commits to do something trivial due to architectural constraints, now after trying to once again merge from develop to test we end up with merge conflicts, of course as i am not very experienced in git and even less my understanding of it's mechanics, i researched about this in git documentation and it is pointed out that squashing commits between two long running branches is not recommended as it inevitably will cause these issues. What i am trying to figure out is, what is the cleanest way to go about:

1. Solving the current merge conflicts
2. Appease the branches so that in the future we'd be able to merge directly from develop to test and NOT from a branch of develop without running into merge conflicts as that goes against the policy we're given
3. (Possibly) avoiding bloating the test branch commit history with all the junk from develop

The approach i was currently thinking of was making a separate branch from develop, opening a MR to "test" with it and solving the conflicts from there, then push that onto develop and then try to merge from develop to test, which however i am not sure would fix it, and also bring some of the "test" commits in the "develop" branch history. Is there a better course of action that will make less of a mess without having to contact repository administrators?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... you will first need to make git understand what you did in the first merge, then you could try the second merge and then *finally* you could post that as a PR to be merged into the `test` branch.... so, first, hunt down the last commit from `develop` that was merged into `test` in the first merge. Let's call this commit `X`. Also, identify the first merge commit in `test` and let's call it `M1`.

So, we will create a new merge commit out of thin air that will be what you should have kept in `test` when you did the first time you merged.... so, something like:

```
git commit-tree -p M1^ -p X -m "what the merge should have been" M1^{tree}
```

That command will print a commit id. Let's call this commit `realM1`.  Check that its history looks ok (it should have as parents the 2 commits of `test` and `develop` that were originally merged. And if you diff `realM1` with `M1`, there should be no differences:

```
git diff realM1..M1
```

If everything looks good, let's check it out and start working from it

```
git checkout realM1
git merge -m "Merging what we have in test" test
```

This should not give much trouble. **If you get conflicts**, then use the tip of `test` as the source of truth, no need to redo any work:

```
git restore --worktree --staged --source test -- .
git merge --continue
```

Now is where the real work begins. We will try the *second* merge of `develop` into this new fake history of `test`.

```
git merge -m "Second merge of develop into test` develop
```

You should *not* see any conflicts that were taken care of in the first merge... it should only be fair and square conflicts related to the second merge. Work on that as usual till you have a final merge commit... which is what you would like to see in the history of `test` having both merges of `develop` in there the way they should have been from the beginning. You could setup a branch over here and push it into a PR... that should be fine.... but the history might be a little messy..... if you would like to see something cleaner, then you can continue like this:

Let's call the result of that second merge `realM2`. Now, let's create *another* commit that only has `test` and `develop` as parents, using what we have in `realM2` as its content:

```
git commit-tree -p test -p develop -m "The real 2nd merge of test and develop" realM2^{tree}
```

Again, we get a commit ID as the output. Set up a branch on it and push it and create a PR to merge into `test`. The history will *still* be a little messy, but not as much as the previous one.

That should work with the minimum effort possible and getting your 2 branch merged *for real* without redoing work.

**Warning**: there is the general assumption that `test` and `develop` are not moving while you are doing this work.

Comment: About your request (3): sorry, you can't. Well... you actually **can**... and then you have to deal with the conflicts that you already took care of before. Take your pick.

Comment: .... or you can try doing all this that you did here every time you need to do a merge.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Would this result in the test branch commit history not having _all_ of the develop commits but just the merge ones? If so, will this result in future merge requests from develop to test not trying to add all the commits? EDIT: just refreshed and read the other comments :-)

Comment: When you merge _for real_ (in git) you _link_ histories... you **will** see the other branch as a parent of the merge commit you are creating.

Comment: If you would _really_ like to avoid having the history clogged with the commits from the other branch, this recipe is actually not what you are after..... you should probably create a _real_ branch where you do _real_ merges and then use things like `git restore` to get the tree of that branch into a _clean_ branch.... but this is hacking... and I would highly advice not to go this way but hey.... this is git, it's _technically_ possible, even if it's not the best course of action.